# How to disable scroll inside a particular view?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, scrollview

I'm trying to get ScrollView to Scroll horizontally only when sliding a particular view
something like this:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
 <View style={styles.TopView}></View>
 <View style={styles.BottomView} Scrollable={false}></View>
</ScrollView>
```

I was thinking of disabling the scroll OnPressIn using hooks like this:

```
const [Scrollmove, setScrollmove] = useState(true);

    <ScrollView horizontal={true} scrollEnabled ={Scrollmove}>
     <View style={styles.TopView}></View>
     <Pressable 
       onPressIn={()=>{setScrollmove(false)}} 
       onPressOut={()=>{setScrollmove(true)}}>
       <View style={styles.BottomView}></View>
     </Pressable>
    </ScrollView>
```

but I don't know if it would work and is there a better way to achieve the desired effect?

**Note**: the code segments I've written above are pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. However, you can change your design like, divide your screen and half of it can be scroll, other half can stay.

```
<View style={styles.TopView}>
   <Text>Stay</Text>
</View>
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
 <View style={styles.BottomView} Scrollable={false}>
 <Text>Scrollable</Text>
</View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: well actually I need both of the views to scroll simultaneously but only the top one controls the scrolling itself